# Running spinach tests in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, bdd, parallel-testing, spinach

I am moving from Cucumber to Spinach for BDD on my rails 4 project. 
According to parallel-tests documentation on https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests
it should support spinach

```
rake parallel:features-spinach       # Spinach
```

but I got that error:

```
4 processes for 40 features, ~ 10 features per process
/home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/racc-     1.4.11/lib/racc/parser.rb:532:in `on_error':  (Racc::ParseError)
parse error on value "\n" (NEWLINE)
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/racc-1.4.11/lib/racc/parser.rb:264:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/racc-1.4.11/lib/racc/parser.rb:264:in `do_parse'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/gherkin-ruby-0.3.1/lib/gherkin_ruby/parser/lexer.rb:31:in `scan_str'
from gherkin.y:107:in `parse'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/gherkin-ruby-0.3.1/lib/gherkin_ruby.rb:8:in `parse'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/lib/spinach/parser.rb:39:in `parse'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/lib/spinach/runner.rb:75:in `block in run'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/lib/spinach/runner.rb:74:in `each'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/lib/spinach/runner.rb:74:in `run'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/lib/spinach/cli.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/gems/spinach-0.8.7/bin/spinach:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/bin/spinach:23:in `load'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/bin/spinach:23:in `<main>'
from /home/pbrudny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@validations/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
```

Just want to know if anybody managed to run Spinach in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to run spinach in parallel. The thing was that paralell testing works only when spinach features are in a default directory

```
/features
```

regardless of **spinach.yml** setting.

I had them in

```
/spinach_features
```

Unfortunatelly parallel tests take longer than regular tests and the output is displayed without colours so basically there are no benefits of using them (at least in my case).